# Hide properties of an Image in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, propertygrid

I have an image that I want to display based on specific choices the user makes. This image shows up as a property in the PropertyGrid. Like this:

[image: screenshot]

The problem is that I am getting all this extraneous information, including the label to the right of the image (System.Drawing.Bitmap) and Image properties underneath it. Is there a way to hide this information in the end product?

**UPDATE:**

I figure it would be relevant to include the code I'm working with.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ImagePropertiesConverter))]
public Image Unsupported
{
    get
    {
        Image image = MyProject.Properties.Resources.Unsupported;
        return image;
    }
}
```

So this property is only shown if the user makes a selection that is unsupported for what they are currently working on. As you can see the property returns an image. I would also like to be able to set the label of the image, currently it shows up in the PropertyGrid as "System.Drawing.Bitmap." If I could take it one step further, I'd like to be able to set the background color of the label. So "System.Drawing.Bitmap" would show up on a red background. I've managed to get rid of the subproperties.

Comment: If you just don't want the image property in the PropertyGrid you can hide it by setting the BrowsableAttribute to false. Is that what you want or are you trying to hide the addition sub-properties?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli I want to hide the subproperties (so everything in the big red box, and even the label to right). The property that displays the image itself will only show if the user makes a specific selection in the the property grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom TypeConverter and flag the Image property with the TypeConverter attribute. See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/908fbba7-7a6e-4ce1-9fa2-1492e015cb94/) for an example.

To get rid of the System.Drawing.Bitmap you use some code like this to override the ConvertTo method in your TypeConverter:

```
public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value is Image && destinationType.Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            return "Text to replace System.Drawing.Bitmap";
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, thank you very much! I just have one more issue. I still can't get rid of the label (System.Drawing.Bitmap). Is that possible?

Comment: Yes you can but I can't remember exactly how, I think you need to override the ConvertToString method in the TypeConverter. I'll have to dig up some old code to get the details to add to my answer

Comment: Thank you, I eagerly await your response as I search Google myself. :P